# Unable to access remote LAN through VPN unless "Use Default Gateway On Remote Network" is enabled

Tags: internet, vpn, gateway

I'm trying to connect to a new VPN we just setup but I can't see the remote LAN if I disable "use default gateway on remote network".  If it's enabled I can see the remote LAN but can't access the internet.

Is this a problem with the client computer configuration or do I need to change something our VPN server?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 8

Comment: Are your LAN and VPN adapter IP settings set to DHCP/automatic under Network and Sharing Centre? If both are automatic then the problem will most probably be that your VPN isn't passing any DNS to your computer whilst VPN connected. I would leave the setting disabled and ask your network admin whether the gateway and DNS addresses are correct. You may also have the VPN and your own LAN IP ranges the same (same subnets) - which won't work...